# Why is this line is in all my postings?

Tags: windows-7

This line is automatically posted in the bottom line every forum that I have written.

How has this remained in my computer for so long and not erased when I shut down?

```
<http://soundfrost.org/ >youtube download
<a href=http://de.soundfrost.org/ >youtube converter</a>
<a href=http://fr.soundfrost.org/ >youtube downloader</a>
<a href=http://fr.soundfrost.org/ >youtube convertisseur</a>
```

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like malware.

Comment: You sure this just isn't part of the forum software?  There are very simple ways to add "ads" to users posts which would mean the action is harmless.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

- check what plugins are installed in your browser and see if anything there relates to downloading videos, or to "soundfrost"
- See if the problem persists no matter which browser you use. If it's not global, which one is affected?
- run a full Malwarebytes scan